# Were they able to stop the Discovery from spinning on the wrong axis?

Tags: 2010-odyssey-two

I’m currently reading *2010: Odyssey Two* and I’m not quite sure if the other crew was able to stop the *Discovery* from spinning on its vertical axis. If so, how did they do this? I must have missed something while reading this.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Please try and make your question titles as specific as possible.

Comment: idk what the close vote is for, if you've read the book or seen the movie it's completely clear what this is asking.

Answer (score 20):

This was accomplished shortly after they came on board

> "*Very cautiously, with many pauses for checking, power was fed to the carousel motors and the great drum was brought up to speed, reabsorbing the spin it had long ago imparted to the ship. Discovery executed a complex series of precessions, until eventually its end-over-end tumble had almost vanished. The last traces of unwanted rotation were neutralized by the attitude-control jets, until the two ships were floating motionless side by side, the squat, stocky Leonov dwarfed by the long, slender Discovery."*